# Access Point Not-Associated : Kali Linux, and Airodump-Ng and wash command freeze

Tags: kali-linux, airmon-ng

In my Kali Linux Airodump-Ng freezes (no wireless networks listed). Trying to execute a wash command also freezes. I can easily get my into monitor mode. How can I get the two to work right?

I'm using kali-linux 1.1.0a - i386, and running it on VMware, on windows 7.

---

Running `**iwconfig**`

[image]

I think that, under ***wlan4 -> mode: managed Access Point: Not Associated***, in the above image (iwconfig) could be the problem, but this is my first day with Kali linux.